# For a Poisson process, prove $P[\lim_{t\to\infty} (1+ \frac{m(t)}{tN(t)})^{N(t)} = e^{\lambda}] = 1$

Tags: poisson-process, renewal-processes

This is the question:

Let $\{N(t): t \ge0\}$ be a Poisson process, and $m(t)$ is its renewal function. Prove:

$$P\left[\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+ \frac{m(t)}{tN(t)}\right)^{N(t)} = e^{\lambda}\right] = 1$$

So, we know for a Poisson process, m(t) which is the renewal function is $\lambda t$. By substituting it, we'll have:

$$ P\left[\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+ \frac{\lambda}{N(t)}\right)^{N(t)} = e^{\lambda}\right] = 1$$

We also know that:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+ \frac{\lambda}{N(t)}\right)^{N(t)} = e^ {\lambda}$$

But what about the probability part? How should we approach that probability equals $1$ part? Does it have something to do with the Strong Law of Large Numbers?

Thanks in advance.
Best

Comment: $N(t)$ is a random variable for each $t$. We know that for any monotonic function $f:[0,\infty[\to\mathbb R$ with $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=\infty$, we have $\lim_{t\to\infty} (1+\frac{\lambda}{f(t)})^{f(t)}=e^\lambda$. So it is enough to prove that, almost surely, $$\lim_{t\to\infty} N(t)=\infty.$$